# sympy:If there is a vector expression in the absolute value, I want to square it

Tags: python, sympy

I want to calculate inner products in the vector module.
If possible, please let me know how to do this without using i or j.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
var('ABx ABy ACx ACy')
N =CoordSys3D('N')
AB=ABx*N.i+ABy*N.j
AC=ACx*N.i+ACy*N.j
BCx2y2=(AC-AB).components[N.i]**2+(AC-AB).components[N.j]**2
B2DtC2=AB.components[N.i]**2+AB.components[N.j]**2-2*(ABx*ACx+ABy*ACy)+AC.components[N.i]**2+AC.components[N.j]**2
f=BCx2y2-B2DtC2
print("#",f.simplify())
# 0
```

What happens when a vector is multiplied by a real number?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
var('ABx ABy ACx ACy p q')
N =CoordSys3D('N')
AB=ABx*N.i+ABy*N.j
AC=ACx*N.i+ACy*N.j
# |pAB-qAC|?
```

(20220614)---------------------------------------------

i try |pAB-qAC|

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
var('ABx ABy ACx ACy p q')
N =CoordSys3D('N')
AB=ABx*N.i+ABy*N.j
AC=ACx*N.i+ACy*N.j
myDot=((((p*AC-q*AB).magnitude())**2-(((p*AC).magnitude())**2+((q*AB).magnitude())**2))/(-2*p*q)).simplify()
print("#",myDot)
# ABx*ACx + ABy*ACy
```

example

i try AB.dot(AC)

```
#  Input:AD=2/5*AB+3/5*AC,|AD|=6/5,|AB|=3,|AC|=2
# Output:AB.dot(AC)
from sympy import *
var('x')
def myMag2Dot(p,q,AD_mag,AB_mag,AC_mag):
    return solve(Eq(((p*AB_mag)**2+2*p*q*x+(q*AC_mag)**2),AD_mag**2),x)[0]
print("#",myMag2Dot(Rational(2,5),Rational(3,5),Rational(6,5),3,2))
# -3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the inner product with the `.dot` method or with the operator `&`. For example:

```
BCx2y2 = (AC-AB) & (AC-AB)
# or: BCx2y2 = (AC-AB).dot(AC-AB)
```

Just in case you need it, you can also compute the cross product with the `.cross` method or with the operator `^`.

Regarding your last question, if you multiply a vector by a scalar quantity (either a number or a symbols), then each component of the vector will be multiplied by it. For example:

```
print(2 * AB)
# out: 2*ABx*N.i + 2*ABy*N.j
```

In your example:

```
p, q = symbols("p, q")
mag = (p * AB - q * AC).magnitude()
print(mag)
# out: sqrt((ABx*p - ACx*q)**2 + (ABy*p - ACy*q)**2)
```